# How to properly execute a script from desktop on Mint KDE 17.2 and Cinnamon 17.3

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux-mint, desktop

I created a simple shell script and copied it onto desktop on the following systems:

On **Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 Beta**: It asks me every time whether I want to *Run in terminal*, which I would like to always do. I am curious on how to make it run without asking?

On **Linux Mint KDE 17.2**: Whatever I tried, I can't figure out, how to execute the script from desktop. I have copied it onto desktop using mouse and set 755 permissions via GUI. It doesn't do anything when I click on it. What do I have to do next?

The script contains only two commands, it's meant to upgrade packages on demand:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: where is the script?. I mean, in what directory?. Then, start a console (terminal) application like (KDE) konsole, cd to the directory above (write `cd dir`), then write `bash ./script` . This seems just too basic. Find a tutorial, read, learn, come back.

Comment: You probably want to create a launcher on the desktop that runs the script.

Comment: @BenjaminStaton Yes, that is correct. I don't know if the script actually copied itself on the desktop while I dragged it on it by mouse or the system did something else.

Comment: @BinaryZebra I dragged it from home folder onto desktop. As I said to BenjaminStaton.

Comment: You don't want to drag it over; you want to leave it in place and create a launcher that points to it.  There's a tutorial at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-desktop-icons-in-kde-and-gnome/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna need a launcher (.desktop file). The options you want are:

- `Exec=gksudo -k -u root /path/toyourscript.sh` Tells the system what to execute and that it needs to be executed as root. You could also simply type in your script here instead of specifying the path to its file, but that's... dirty.
- `Terminal=true` Makes it open in terminal

Also, you probably should use `dist-upgrade` because it's more stability-friendly. This is how my .desktop looked when I was doing something like that:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Updater
Comment=short script
Type=Application
Exec=gksudo -k -u root /home/andrzej/Documents/update.sh
Terminal=true
Categories=
```

`upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` should also require confirmation. When you run them in terminal you can simply type y and press enter, but if you run it with .desktop it will close on confirmation, so you need to add `-y` option, like this: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`